# Generalized coordinates as components

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, vectors, constrained-dynamics

Why we cannot express Generalized coordinates as a vector like we do with Cartesian coordinates $x$ , $y$ ,$z$ ?

Comment: Think about the following example: Are spherical coordinates a vector?

Comment: @Qmechanic Radius $r$ will be the component of the position vector ($\mathbf{r} = r \hat{r}$). But if we consider all of them $r, \theta, \phi$ then not.

Answer (score 0):

You can put like a vector, for example, if we change the coordinate system $(x,y,z)\Rightarrow (r,\theta,\phi)$ you can put a vector $v=a\hat r+b\hat \theta+c\hat \phi$. I think you are refaring why lagrangian formalism does not appear vectors

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the 1st and 2nd geodetic problems? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems)

1. *"Given a point (in terms of its coordinates) and the direction (azimuth) and distance from that point to a second point, determine (the coordinates of) that second point."*
2. *"Given two points, determine the azimuth and length of the line (straight line, arc or geodesic) that connects them."*

The reason I mention them is because a point, as defined by coordinates, is not a vector. A point lives in an affine space, which assigns coordinates to every point, and has some arbitrary origin where, usually, all the coordinates are zero. (As opposed to a vector space, where $\vec 0$ has special significance).

The difference between two points *is* a vector (2nd problem), and a point plus a vector is another point (1st problem).

Now when we use Cartesian coordinates to define a point in 3D Euclidean space

$$ p_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i) $$

we easily find the difference between that point and the origin:

$$ p_i - 0 = (x_i, y_i, z_i) - (0,0,0) = x_i\hat{\bf x} + y_i\hat{\bf y} + y_i\hat{\bf y} \equiv \vec{\bf p}_i = [x_i, y_i, z_i]$$

Notice the striking similarity in the representation of the point, $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$, and the representation of the vector, $[x_i, y_i, z_i]$; they are both three numbers (the *same* three numbers) in some kind of bracket.

That can lead one to conclude that the point, $p_i$, and vector, $\vec{\bf p}_i$, are the same thing. They are not.

Note that if I represent the point in spherical coordinates:

$$ p_i = (r_i\sin{\theta_i}\cos{\phi_i}, r_i\sin{\theta_i}\sin{\phi_i}, r_i\cos{\theta_i}) $$

then it is still the same  point, but it looks nothing like the vector separating it from the origin:

$$\vec{\bf p}_i = p_i - 0 = x_i\hat{\bf x} + y_i\hat{\bf y} + y_i\hat{\bf y}  $$

even if I use the local basis $(\hat{\bf r}_i, \hat{\bf \theta}_i, \hat{\bf \phi}_i)$:

$$\vec{\bf p}_i  = r_i\hat{\bf r}_i = (r_i, 0, 0)_i$$